# PowerShell Script Issues with Variable Values

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write this script to restart computers only if they are Offline.  The script for getting user infomration works but I cannot get the variable values for the restart portion at the bottom of the script.  Does anyone have a suggestion?  I am somewhat new to Powershell, but writing code.  Example of my script follows:

```
Function Get-LoggedOnUser
    {
    Param
    (
        $ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
        $Credential
    )

    Function Test-RemoteRegistry
    {
    Param
        (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [switch]$Enable
        ,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $False)]
        [switch]$Disable
        ,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [String[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        )
    Begin
        {
        $PipelineInput = (-not $PSBOUNDPARAMETERS.ContainsKey("ComputerName")) -and (-not $ComputerName)
        
        Function Test ($Computer)
            {
            Try
                {
                [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine, $Computer) | Out-Null 
                #20ms faster than Get-Service per computer! Not sure how to handle/check things like the firewall though...


                #If we hit here without error Remote Reg is enabled.
                If ($Disable)
                    {
                    Try
                        {
                        Get-Service -Name RemoteRegistry -ComputerName $Computer | Set-Service -Status Stopped -ErrorAction Stop
                        Return $False
                        #If we hit here without error Remote Reg is now disabled.
                        }
                    Catch
                        {
                        Return $True
                        #If we hit here, we couldn't stop remote registry.
                        }
                    }
                Else
                    {
                    Return $True 
                    }
                }
            Catch
                {
                If ($Enable)
                    {
                    Try
                        {
                        Get-Service -Name RemoteRegistry -ComputerName $Computer | Set-Service -Status Running -ErrorAction Stop
                        Return $True 
                        #If we hit here without error Remote Reg is now enabled.
                        }
                    Catch
                        {
                        Return $False
                        #If we hit here, we couldn't start remote registry.
                        }
                    }
                Else
                    {
                    Return $False
                    #If we hit here remote registry is disabled.
                    }
                }
            }
        
        }
    Process
        {
        If ($PipelineInput)
            {
            Test $_
            }
        Else
            {
            $ComputerName | ForEach-Object {
                Test $_
                }
            }
        }

    }


    Foreach ($Computer in $Computername)
        {
        $Online = $False
        $User = $False
        $Locked = $False
        If (Test-Connection $Computer -Count 2 -Quiet) 
            {
            $Online = $True 
            If ($Credential) 
                {
                $User = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credential | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName -ErrorAction Stop
                }
            Else
                {
                $User = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $Computer | Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName -ErrorAction Stop
                }
            If (Test-RemoteRegistry -Enable -ComputerName $Computer)
                {
                If ((Get-Process logonui -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -and ($user))
                    {
                    $Locked = $True
                    }
            }
            }
        $Output = New-Object PSObject
        $Output | Add-Member noteproperty ComputerName $Computer
        $Output | Add-Member noteproperty Online $Online
        $Output | Add-Member noteproperty Username $User
        $Output | Add-Member noteproperty Locked $Locked
        $Output
        }
    }




Get-LoggedOnUser





If (($Online) -eq $False)
    {Shutdown /r t 0 /m \\$Computername}

ELSE
    {Write-host 'HELLO  $Online $Computername'}
```

I just want this for a single user as I am using PDQ Inventory to roll out the script.  The variables at the end of the script are $null?

Answer (score 0):

- Variables defined in a *child scope* - in which functions run by default - are never seen by the calling scope. See the conceptual [about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes) help topic
- It's best for functions to communicate values to the caller via their *output* ("return value"), which you're function is already doing: it outputs *objects* whose properties contain the values of interest.

Therefore:

```bash
Get-LoggedOnUser |
  ForEach-Object { # Loop over all output objects
    # Refer to the object at hand via the automatic $_ variable.
    # Note the use of "..." (expandable strings) so as to support
    # expansion (string interpolation).
    if (-not $_.Online) { Shutdown /r t 0 /m "\\$($_.ComputerName)" }
    else                { "HELLO  $($_.Online) $($_.ComputerName)" }
  }
```